# how pass two parameters each time to a .exe file through .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file passing two arguments to a .exe file

like this

```
webserviceclient 300000 category
```

here `webserviceclient`  is .exe file name and two others are arguments to .exe file.

Like above,I have another another two batch files passing same .exe file name with different two args.

like

```
  webserviceclient 300000 Item
  webserviceclient 300000 department
```

every time i am double click on each batch file to run. these batch file are in windows C drive and exe file also in same drive.
Now i want to write these all batch files in one single batch file to double click once run all, if any error arise in any one command i want show the error in same command prompt.

help some body.

Comment: How does the `webserviceclient` report errors?

Comment: And what's the problem to write all three lines into one batch??

Comment: hi,thanks to replay, in my case if not successful execute in .exe  file with these args. ex: 'file not found'.

Comment: when i run single batch file individually, the in the command prompt it is showing C:\>webserviceclient 300000 Item , but when combine three lines, it is showing webserviceclient 300000 Item                                webserviceclient 300000 department.... like without C:\>. so is this cause any problem?

Comment: have you put a new line for each command?

Comment: yes,each command in separate line

Comment: Each command should be in it's own line. Make sure that the newline character is either a LF (Line Feed \n ) or (CR Carriage return, \r) followed by LF  (CR+LF, '\r\n'). The issue you mention  in the comment above is caused when your line ending is a single  CR (CR Carriage return, \r) and the \n Line Feed is missing. You can verify this by opening the batch file in any texteditor that shows you the invisible characters.
To fix this create a new batch file, open it in notepad and type each command. Don't copy and paste.

Comment: hi  Jamleck, i am unable to get exact, please can you give a example with my command.